# addEventListener, arrow functions, and `this`

Tags: javascript, this

I'm going through the JavaScript30 challenge, and in [lesson 3](https://github.com/wesbos/JavaScript30/blob/master/03%20-%20CSS%20Variables/index-FINISHED.html) he's got some event listener calling a function that references the element it's called on as `this`:

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.controls input');
function handleUpdate() {
  const suffix = this.dataset.sizing || '';
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--${this.name}`, this.value + suffix);
}
inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', handleUpdate));
inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('mousemove', handleUpdate));
```

I'm trying to rewrite it with ES6 arrow function, but I can't get the `this` to work right. I got a workaround using `target`:

```
const handleUpdate = (e) => {
  const that = e.target;
  const newValue = `${that.value}${that.dataset.sizing || ''}`;
  etc.
}
```

but I first tried to bind the function like that:

```
input.addEventListener('change', handleUpdate.bind(this));
```

But `this` inside the function still points to `window` and I don't understand why.

Is there no "right" way to bind the function to the element in this case?

Comment: If you want to use `this` then you need to use regular functions. Arrow functions don't really work properly with `this`.

Comment: Also, is there any right way to do this with arrow functions? **No**

Comment: I think I recall reading something that said, or suggested, that Arrow functions were written expressly to avoid affecting the 'this'.

Comment: Either a normal function and `this` or `e.currentTarget` (not `e.target`!!)

Comment: Arrow functions are only allowed to inherit the value of 'this' from the environment they were defined in, rather than the context they were invoked in. The demo code uses a regular function, and 'this' references the environment in which it's invoked. That isn't possible with arrow functions by definition, hence why they can't be used anywhere you need to use 'this'.

Answer (score 10):

### What is this?

`this` is a special keyword in Javascript that refers to the executing environment of the function:

- If you execute a function in the global scope, `this` will be bound to the window
- If you pass the function to a callback for an event handler, `this` will be bound to the DOM element that raised the event

### Binding

The bind method basically says, when you call the function, replace this with whatever my argument is. So, for example:

```
let a = {}
function test_this() {
     return this === a;
}  

test_this(); // false
test_this.bind(a)(); // true (.bind() returns the bound function so we need to call the bound function to see the result)
```

Additionally arrow functions are simply syntactic sugar for binding the function's `this` to the current value of `this`. For example,

```
let b = () => { /* stuff */ }
```

is the same as

```
let b = (function () { /* stuff */}).bind(this);
```

*(basically, I know this is an oversimplication)*

### Your predicament

In the normal course of events (not using arrow functions), `this` is bound to the DOM element.

When you're executing the creation of the event handler `input.addEventListener('change', handleUpdate.bind(this));` you're running in the global scope (so `this === window`). So you're effectively running `input.addEventListener('change', handleUpdate.bind(window));` (which is the behavior you're noticing). And using the arrow function is the same thing.

If you want to replace the callback with an anonymous function you should instead do:

```
const handleUpdate = function (e) {
  const that = e.target;
  const newValue = `${that.value}${that.dataset.sizing || ''}`;
  // etc.
}
```

Comment: Arrow functions have no concept of `this`. `this` inside of an arrow function is whatever `this` is in their containing lexical environment.

Comment: Hence the "I know this is an oversimplification". I think trying to discuss lexical scoping when someone is just learning JS is probably not the best pedagogical method. If you're reading this and want the more correct explanation: arrow functions don't bind `this` so `this` simply refers to whatever it referred to in the enclosing lexical scope. However that is functionally the same to if they had just bound this to the enclosing scope.

Comment: The point is that your entire answer can be replaced with "Arrow functions have no concept of this. this inside of an arrow function is whatever this is in their containing lexical environment. Don't use arrow functions if you need to bind the value of `this`." and possibly some references to the ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification.

Comment: That would fail to explain why his attempt with .bind didn't work

Comment: It most definitely would explain why his attempt to bind didn't work "Arrow functions have no concept of this. this inside of an arrow function is whatever this is in their containing lexical environment. Don't use arrow functions if you need to bind the value of this."

Comment: I'm referring to `input.addEventListener('change', handleUpdate.bind(this));`

Comment: And again, the reason that bind did not work there is because "Arrow functions have no concept of this. this inside of an arrow function is whatever this is in their containing lexical environment. Don't use arrow functions if you need to bind the value of this."

Comment: My apologies, I think there is a misunderstanding -- I don't believe that he/her is trying to .bind(this), I think they're wondering why this in the function doesn't correspond to the DOM element they expect it should...

Comment: No, the code in the question would definitely work as expected if they were to not use arrow functions. The reason that this in the function does not correspond to the DOM element the expect it should is because "Arrow functions have no concept of this. this inside of an arrow function is whatever this is in their containing lexical environment. Don't use arrow functions if you need to bind the value of this."

Comment: doing `input.addEventListener('change', (function () {/*stuff*/}).bind(this));` would not work, regardless of if they're using arrow functions

Comment: `inputs.forEach(function(input) { input.addEventListener('change', handleUpdate.bind(this)) });` would most definitely have worked if `handleUpdate` had not been defined using an arrow function.

Comment: I agree fully. But their question explicitly asks about the .Bind case at the bottom

Comment: Which is obviously extracted from the `inputs.forEach` function call. Regardless, the whole problem could be solved by simply not using arrow functions when `this` is important. You're making this far more complicated than it should be. The long and short of it is... well I've already stated the long and short of it multiple times. I'm not going to repeat myself again. Good day.