# how to sumbit form with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

I saw this code from the internet and I want to understand somethings - https://codepen.io/FlorinPop17/pen/OJJKQeK

And I try to POST form after all the parms are valid.

The valid is in the client browser (and also in server side).

I want after the all inputs are valid to POST the inputs to `<form action="/postdata">`

```
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
    <h2>Create Account</h2>
</div>
<form id="form" class="form">
    <div class="form-control">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="florinpop17" id="username" />
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
        <small>Error message</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
        <label for="username">Email</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="a@florin-pop.com" id="email" />
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
        <small>Error message</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
        <label for="username">Password</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"/>
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
        <small>Error message</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
        <label for="username">Password check</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password two" id="password2"/>
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
        <small>Error message</small>
    </div>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS -

```
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const username = document.getElementById('username');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const password = document.getElementById('password');
const password2 = document.getElementById('password2');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    checkInputs();
});

function checkInputs() {
    // trim to remove the whitespaces
    const usernameValue = username.value.trim();
    const emailValue = email.value.trim();
    const passwordValue = password.value.trim();
    const password2Value = password2.value.trim();
    
    if(usernameValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(username, 'Username cannot be blank');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(username);
    }
    
    if(emailValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(email, 'Email cannot be blank');
    } else if (!isEmail(emailValue)) {
        setErrorFor(email, 'Not a valid email');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(email);
    }
    
    if(passwordValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(password, 'Password cannot be blank');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(password);
    }
    
    if(password2Value === '') {
        setErrorFor(password2, 'Password2 cannot be blank');
    } else if(passwordValue !== password2Value) {
        setErrorFor(password2, 'Passwords does not match');
    } else{
        setSuccessFor(password2);
    }
}

function setErrorFor(input, message) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    const small = formControl.querySelector('small');
    formControl.className = 'form-control error';
    small.innerText = message;
}

function setSuccessFor(input) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    formControl.className = 'form-control success';
}
    
function isEmail(email) {
    return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email);
}
```

Comment: So do not cancel it `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

So, after checking the validity and make sure that all valid, then send a `fetch` request with `POST` method to `/postdata` with a body equal to object with `input`s value.

```
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const username = document.getElementById('username');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const password = document.getElementById('password');
const password2 = document.getElementById('password2');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if (checkInputs()) {
       fetch('/postdata', {
          body: {
             username: username.value,
             email: email.value,
             password: password.value,
             password2: password2.value,
          },
          method: 'POST',
       })
    }
});

function checkInputs() {
    // trim to remove the whitespaces
    const usernameValue = username.value.trim();
    const emailValue = email.value.trim();
    const passwordValue = password.value.trim();
    const password2Value = password2.value.trim();
    let isValid = true
    if(usernameValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(username, 'Username cannot be blank');
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(username);
    }
    
    if(emailValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(email, 'Email cannot be blank');
        isValid = false;
    } else if (!isEmail(emailValue)) {
        setErrorFor(email, 'Not a valid email');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(email);
    }
    
    if(passwordValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(password, 'Password cannot be blank');
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(password);
    }
    
    if(password2Value === '') {
        setErrorFor(password2, 'Password2 cannot be blank');
        isValid = false;
    } else if(passwordValue !== password2Value) {
        setErrorFor(password2, 'Passwords does not match');
        isValid = false;
    } else{
        setSuccessFor(password2);
    }
    return isValid;
}

function setErrorFor(input, message) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    const small = formControl.querySelector('small');
    formControl.className = 'form-control error';
    small.innerText = message;
}

function setSuccessFor(input) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    formControl.className = 'form-control success';
}
    
function isEmail(email) {
    return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment but your solutions doesnt work...

Answer (score 0):

### Critical Details

There are a ton of changes to OP, but only a few changes are actually important. The `<form>` attributes should be as follows:

```
<form id="main" action="/postdata" method="POST">
```

The `action` value is a relative location, it's correct as long as the `<form>` is in the same domain as the server. Otherwise, it'll be something like: `https://serverDomain.com/postData`.

Next, the event handler triggered by the "submit" event needs to check each `"div.form-control"` to see if they all have the class: `".success"` after the `checkInputs()` function runs. If they do, then the `<form>` needs to be submitted.

```
main.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  checkInputs();
  if (Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".form-control"))
    .every(div => div.classList.contains("success"))) {
    this.submit();
  }
});
```

The example above should work with the OP unchanged. Note the anonymous event handler is **not** an arrow function. IMO arrow function event handlers are limiting because the keyword `this` is useless (see [addEventListener, arrow functions, and `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41914596/2813224)).

### Other Changes

Although many things have changed from the OP in the example, fundamentally they are the same, it's just I wrote it a little better.

- Some elements were changed into form controls which provided added features, made more easily accessible, and even better semantically.

  ```
  <div class="form-control"> 
  <!--from-
    --to--> 
  <fieldset name="formControl">

  <small>
  <!--from-
    --to-->
  <output name="message">
  ```
- [HTMLFormElement](https://javascript.info/form-elements) and
  [HTMLFormControlsCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) interfaces are used to reference the `<form>` and it's [form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#form-associated_content). The syntax is succinct and specialized so there's more control with less code.
- Functions `isUser()` and `isPass()` are added to impose real criteria for `username` and `password` values.
- The `error()` function (in OP it is `setErrorFor()`) has an third optional `@param {string} criteria -`  which adds a `<input type="button">` that opens a [`<dialog>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) that displays the given string `criteria`.
- When the `<form>` is successfully submitted, the data is sent to a live test server. The response is captured and displayed in the `<iframe>` located at the bottom of the page.

```js
const main = document.forms.main;
const fc = main.elements;
const user = fc.username;
const email = fc.email;
const pass = fc.password;
const check = fc.check;
const details = fc.details;
const modal = details.parentElement;

main.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  checkInputs();
  if (Array.from(fc.formControl).every(fSet => fSet.classList.contains("valid"))) {
    this.submit();
  }
});

main.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const clicked = e.target;
  if (clicked !== this) {
    if (clicked.name === "more") {
      modal.showModal();
      details.value = clicked.dataset.text;
    }
    if (clicked.id === "close") {
      modal.close();
    }
  }
});

function checkInputs() {
  const userData = user.value.trim();
  const emailData = email.value.trim();
  const passData = pass.value.trim();
  const checkData = check.value.trim();

  if (userData === "") {
    error(user, "Username is blank, enter data");
  } else if (!isUser(userData)) {
    error(user, "Username must have at least 8 characters", "A minimum of 8 characters in any combination of lower case letters, upper case letters, and digits");
  } else {
    valid(user);
  }

  if (emailData === "") {
    error(email, "Email is blank, enter data");
  } else if (!isEmail(emailData)) {
    error(email, "Email address is invalid", "Email address must have 1 or more characters, an ampersand:  @, followed by 1 or more charaters, a dot: ., followed by 1 or more characters");
  } else {
    valid(email);
  }

  if (passData === "") {
    error(pass, "Password is blank, enter data");
  } else if (!isPass(passData)) {
    error(pass, "Password must have at least 8 character", "Password must have a minimum of 8 characters with at least 1 lower case letter, 1 upper case letter, 1 digit, and 1 symbol (!, @, #, $, %, ^, &, *, _, =, +, -)");
  } else {
    valid(pass);
  }

  if (checkData === "") {
    error(check, "Password check is blank, enter data");
  } else if (passData !== checkData) {
    error(check, "Passwords do not match");
  } else {
    valid(check);
  }
}

function error(input, message, criteria) {
  const set = input.parentElement;
  const msg = set.elements.message;
  set.classList.add('error');
  set.classList.remove('valid');
  msg.value = message;
  if (criteria) {
    msg.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<input name="more" class="more" type="button" value="..." data-text="${criteria}">`);
  }
}

function valid(input) {
  const set = input.parentElement;
  const msg = set.elements.message;
  set.classList.add('valid');
  set.classList.remove('error');
  msg.value = "";
}

function isUser(name) {
  const rgx = /[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}/g;
  return rgx.test(name);
}

function isEmail(address) {
  const rgx = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/g;
  return rgx.test(address);
}

function isPass(secret) {
  const rgx = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_=+-]).{8,}$/g;
  return rgx.test(secret);
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,500&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font: 400 2ch/1.15 'Open Sans'
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: #9b59b6;
}

form {
  padding: 30px 40px;
}

fieldset {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 0;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

.data {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font: inherit;
}

.data:focus {
  border-color: #777;
  outline: 0;
}

.success .data {
  border-color: #2ecc71;
}

.error .data {
  border-color: #e74c3c;
}

i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  right: 15px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.valid i.fa-check-circle {
  color: #2ecc71;
  visibility: visible;
}

.error i.fa-exclamation-circle {
  color: #e74c3c;
  visibility: visible;
}

output {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 15px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  color: #e74c3c;
  background: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #8e44ad;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  font: inherit;
  background: #8e44ad;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.more {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  right: -1.75rem;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.error output,
.error .more {
  visibility: visible;
}

#details {
  position: static;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  visibility: visible;
}

#close {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<form id="main" action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="POST" target="response">
  <fieldset name="formControl">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" class="data" type="text" placeholder="user01" />
    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
    <output name="message"></output>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="formControl">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" name="email" class="data" type="text" placeholder="user01@email.com" />
    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
    <output name="message"></output>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="formControl">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" class="data" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
    <output name="message"></output>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="formControl">
    <label for="check">Password Check</label>
    <input id="check" name="check" class="data" type="password" placeholder="Password as entered previously" />
    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
    <output name="message"></output>
  </fieldset>
  <button>Submit</button>
  <iframe name="response"></iframe>
  <dialog>
    <output id="details"></output>
    <input id="close" type="button" value="OK">
  </dialog>
</form>
```